# jQuery mobile flipswitch refresh causes angularjs digest error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I have this angularjs directive that wraps around jQuery mobile flipswitch widget:

```
mcb.directive('jSwitch', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            label: '@',
            value: '=',
            disabled: '@',
            mini: '@',
            switch: '&',
            offlabel: '@',
            onlabel: '@',
            onval: '=',
            offval: '='
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'tpl/widget/jswitch.htm',
        compile: function (e) {
            e.trigger('create');
            return {
                post: function (s, e, a) {
                    s.$watch('value', function () {
                        return e.find('#' + a.id).flipswitch('refresh');
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

---

```
<label for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label>
<select id="{{id}}"
        name="{{id}}"
        data-role="flipswitch"
        data-ng-model="value"
        data-mini="{{mini}}">
    <option value="{{offval}}">{{offlabel}}</option>
    <option value="{{onval}}">{{onlabel}}</option>
</select>
```

I expect it to refresh all flipswitch widgets on my application that are bound to same model, once the model value changed.

This code does work, but the `return e.find('#' + a.id).flipswitch('refresh');` line causes angularjs digest error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at Error (native)
    at http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/ajs/ajs.js:6:450
    at k (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/ajs/ajs.js:106:41)
    at h.$apply (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/ajs/ajs.js:113:301)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/ajs/ajs.js:208:36)
    at HTMLSelectElement.m.event.dispatch (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3:8440)
    at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3:5150)
    at Object.m.event.trigger (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3:7541)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3:15408)
    at Function.m.extend.each (http://d.h/mcb/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js:2:2973)
```

I know that the error is caused by `flipswitch('refresh')` at least I think so, because I if I remove it, error dissapears, but then I am missing needed functionality.

Comment: Do you call refresh when the flip's value is changed or when you create it?

Comment: When the value changes.

Comment: So you change the value programmatically when the switch is in DOM not before creating it?

Comment: Value is changed when the model changes, so in a sense yes it it changed programmatically, but not in a way I can control it (At least I think so).

Comment: I don't know how angular js works; when model is changed, does it replace existing element with a new one? Or just update its' value?